# Script that verify a whitelist of domains

Tags: php, regex

I have easy question. I need to verify a string and validate a whitelist domain like this:

```
$WList = array('mega.co.nz','mediafire.com','putlocker.com','');
$Dominio = str_replace("www.","",parse_url($EnlaceUrl,PHP_URL_HOST));
if(in_array($Dominio,$WList)){//ok}
```

but this method doesnt retieve me domains like:

```
www42.zippyshare.com,www51.zippyshare.com,www71.zippyshare.com,www23.zippyshare.com
```

how resolve this problem? :)

Comment: what are you exactly asking for?

Comment: Where does `$EnlaceUrl` come from? What ***exactly*** are you trying to do?

Comment: $Dominio = preg_replace("/www(.*?)\./","",parse_url($EnlaceUrl,PHP_URL_HOST));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this which removes all that begin with `www` until the first dot (inclusive):

```
$Dominio = preg_replace('~^www[^.]*\.~', '', parse_url($EnlaceUrl,PHP_URL_HOST));
```

Comment: The literal dot should be part of the match too I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
if (preg_match('/[\w\d-]+\.(\w{3,4}|(\w{2,3}\.\w{2}))$/', $Dominio, $match))
    $Dominio = $match[1];
```

It will convert `anything.domainname.suffix` into `domainname.suffix` so you can test against your list.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another preg_match example :

```
if(preg_match("/(?:([^.]+).)?([^.]+).([^\\/]+)/", $Dominio, $m)) {
    $Dominio = $m[2] . '.' $m[3];
}
```

Comment: with this regexp, i will retrive me the domaind and suffix without exception? ej subdomain.domain.com, www1.subdomain.com, w.subdomain.com

Comment: Yes, `blah.domain.co.uk` will return `m[1] = 'blah', m[2] = 'domain', m[3] = 'co.uk'`